# Resizing of window causes button to move in next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form

http://jsfiddle.net/sQY4u/2/

If you try to resize it to the right you will noticed that the image (submit button) is going on the next line. I have percentages in width and don't understand why is doing this.

The input text area that should get resized properly has percentage width. The submit button has fixed width, but also tried with percentage width just that the image is getting cut. I tried with a lower percentage on the div

```
<div style="width:80%;">
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" onfocus="validateonfocus()" onBlur="validateonblur()" value="Enter Domain" />
</div>
```

but the space between the end of the form and the input is too much. Any ideeas on how to overcome this.

Comment: It works for me in `FF 27.0.1`

Comment: @KristerAndersson Oh, sorry, added the wrong style css. Check now http://jsfiddle.net/sQY4u/2/

Comment: Try breaking out your CSS and HTML.  It is much easier to troubleshoot then.

Comment: +1 @zsaat. The sole purpose of css is to separate document structure and styling... iMHO is to first start doing that.

Comment: make div width 80% and button's 16% then it will work on resize. see fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/sQY4u/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/sQY4u/26/)

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute position for submit button.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, it's because you are using percentage width that this is happening.
When the `div` element becomes too small, the button will have no space to fit on the right and it will have no other choice but go to the next line.You can set the width of the div surrounding the textbox to 300px and the button will stay in it's place (but the text 'domain name' will be cut off).
http://jsfiddle.net/sQY4u/18/

Edit:
Here is the solution to the problem. I have set the width of the form to `500px` and `400px` to the textbox which will give enough space to write the domain name, and the button will stay nest to it.
http://jsfiddle.net/sQY4u/24/

Comment: Well it's quite the opposite. if you specify values in pixels it'll always be stay the same. If you use %, it'll change according to the window size. for responsiveness it's better to use % in most of the cases.

Comment: @Tilwin I'm not saying that using the % is bad, but the way he used it will actually break the page when it is resized since there will be no more space to fit the button. And if you set a % to the button you will be deforming it what will make an even worse effect